# Is this a correct type of URL address?

Tags: url

Hi if the 2 domain names www.xyz.com and www.abc.com are correct AND xyz.com is the server where abc.com is hosted, will the address www.xyz.com/www.abc.com work? This question is to try and solve a legal problem!

Thanks,

Henry

Answer (score 1):

No it will not work. Usually you would employ vHosts to run multiple domains on one machine. These can distinguish either by IP (if you have one IP per Domain) or by which domain is requested in the HTTP header (if you share one IP for both domains).

So, basically which website you get depends on your request. The address www.xyz.com/www.abc.com should provide an 404 error. Except if the admin configured it on purpose to response to that request.

Further reading: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/name-based.html

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a strange question.

If you have two domains which both point to one server, the address www.domain1.com www.domain2.com will be a virtual host on that server.

Each virtual host will have their own home folder if configured correctly

and www.domain1.com/something will be a folder called something within the DocumentRoot of www.domain1.com

From the moment you add a / after the domain the web server on that machine will try to look up the local document  root for anything beyond that point

Even with an awfully badly configured web server this is not likely to work since it goes back to above after / is DocumentRoot folder it be looking for

so unless you have
Assuming domain1's Document Root is  : /var/www/domain1/

if you have 
/var/www/domain1/www.domain2.com { which has all the content of www.domain2.com then its not going to work

Answer (score 0):

`www.xyz.com/www.abc.com` is a valid URI and points to the resource at the *path* `/www.abc.com` on host `www.xyz.com`. `www.xyz.com/www.abc.com` would return a resource as long as something exists at this path at the host.

Whether or not `www.xyz.com/www.abc.com` works is not dependent on whether or not `xyz.com` and `abc.com` are related. The *host* `www.abc.com` may just as well not exist, as it is not referred to.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax